# Failed login attempt on Castopod Dev Setup - Ubuntu

Tags: php, docker

I wanted to set up castopod dev following [these instructions](https://docs.castopod.org/contributing/setup-development.html) on Ubuntu in VirtualBox with [Docker installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).
I added test admin user with `php spark db:seed TestSeeder`.

While logging on `localhost:8.0.0.8/cp-auth/login` with:
email -  **admin@example.com**
password - **AGUehL3P**
the error "Unable to login you. Please check the password." appears.

On the phpMyAdmin database, for that admin user, there is no password "AGUehL3P"" but a hashed version in the "secret2" field. I am not sure if there is a problem with that hash or somewhere else.
I tried to change "secret2" field to simpler password e.g. "admin", but the problem with login error still persist. In documentation there is mentioned "login: admin" but not "admin@example.com" as login and I am confused where should I put "login: admin" credentials.

What sould I do to be able to login on my local Castopod?